# Why Solidity assembly calldataload at the offset 0xC4?

Tags: solidity

ChainBridge has [a piece of solidity code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/handlers/ERC20Handler.sol#L103):

```
assembly {

            amount := calldataload(0xC4)   // **why get data from 0xC4？

            recipientAddress := mload(0x40)
            lenRecipientAddress := calldataload(0xE4)   // offset 0x20 beside amount is the length variable, I know that.
            mstore(0x40, add(0x20, add(recipientAddress, lenRecipientAddress)))  // load address to the free memory

            calldatacopy(
                recipientAddress, // copy to destinationRecipientAddress
                0xE4, // copy from calldata @ 0x104        **Why copy from 0xE4？
                sub(calldatasize(), 0xE) // copy size (calldatasize - 0x104)    
                //** Why the length is calldatasize()-0xE? Is the original comment by the author correct?
            )
        }
```

The function `deposit` has 5 arguments, I know that the assembly code wants to get `amount` from the `data` argument. But I can't figure out

1. why the offset is `0xC4`, I try to calculate the offset from the first argument of the the function `deposit`. Is the offset of `data` argument: 4bytes(method sig)+32bytes(bytes32)+32bytes(uint8)+32bytes(uint64)+32bytes(address)? But the sum up is not 0xC4.
2. why does `calldatacopy` use an offset `0xE4` and `0xE`
3. Is the original comment by the author correct?

The `data` argument consists of: `amount`, `lenRecipientAddress` and `recipientAddress`

The invocation path is : [bridgeContract.depoist](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/Bridge.sol#L302) -> [ERC20Handler.deposit](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/handlers/ERC20Handler.sol#L90), the input of data please refer [the link](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-deploy/blob/v1.0.0/cb-sol-cli/cmd/erc20.js#L59), the data argument is passed transparently.

Another confuses me is that the ERC721Handler `depoist` function.
The input data is like [this](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-deploy/blob/v1.0.0/cb-sol-cli/cmd/erc721.js#L75), the data consists of `id`,`lenRecipientAddress` and `recipientAddress`. The only difference is ERC721Handler use 32bytes `id`,  the ERC20Handler use 32bytes `amount`, but their total length is the same. So from my perspective both of ERC20Handler and ERC721Handler should have the exact same code, but the last line code `sub(calldatasize(), 0xE4)` is different, the offset `0xE4` in ERC721Handler is different to the `0xE` in the ERC20Handler.

The ERC721Handler's `depoist`:

```
calldatacopy(
                destinationRecipientAddress,    // copy to destinationRecipientAddress
                0xE4,                           // copy from calldata after destinationRecipientAddress length declaration @0xE4
                sub(calldatasize(), 0xE4)       // copy size (calldatasize - (0xE4 + 0x20))  
                //** Why use 0xE4? Is the original comment by the author correct?
            )
```

The invocation path is : [bridgeContract.depoist](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/Bridge.sol#L302) -> [ERC721Handler.deposit](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/handlers/ERC721Handler.sol#L101), the data argument is passed transparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ The calculation is missing the two slots required by `data`, first slot is the offset within the calldata, and the second slot is the length in bytes. That will be 4 + 32 x 4 + 32 x 2 = 196 = 0xc4.

2/ 0xe4 is the start of recipientAddress length. The 0xe seems to be a mistake, from the comment they wanted to write `sub(calldatasize(), 0xe4)`. It shouldn't be a problem since data calldatacopy will return 0 for bytes outside calldatasize().

3/ <s>It appears to be correct</s>. The numbers are wrong.

Comment: 1) What is the last instruction of`calldatacopy ` used for ?  copy the len and recipientAddress to the target memory? or the code's real intention is to copy the recipientAddress to the target memory?  2) 0xE4 !=0x104!=104 decimal, so the comment is not correct?

Comment: @gfan 1/ It copies data from calldata area to memory. The intention is copying the recipientAddress as it were a "string", strings have its length in front. 2/ You are correct, the numbers are wrong.